# Minimum number of perfect matchings in a regular bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, lower-bounds, bipartite-graphs, perfect-matchings

Is there a lower bound on the number of perfect matchings in a $k$-regular bipartite graph?

One can use Hall's marriage theorem and induction on $k$ to derive the lower bound of $k$. I can't come up with an example where this bound is actually tight. Is there a better lower bound than this?

Comment: Are you aware of this lower bound? http://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/countpms2.pdf

Comment: This paper has a survey that includes Schrijver's bound and some more recent bounds due to Gurvits: http://homepages.cwi.nl/~monique/files/monthly903-911-schrijver.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as already mentioned in the comments,
that is answered by Alexander Schrijver in his publication "**Counting 1-factors in regular bipartite graphs**":

> any $k$-regular bipartite graph with $2n$ vertices has at least $$\left(\frac{(k-1)^{k-1}}{k^{k-2}}\right)^n$$ perfect matchings.

Comment: This bound was already given by Anurag in the comments: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182989/minimum-number-of-perfect-matchings-in-a-regular-bipartite-graph#comment458813_182989

Comment: @WillSawin sorry, I didn't check the comments for answers.

Comment: It's good to have the result written out here, as the links in the comments could die at any time.